Alternative to hardware interface
I am new to ROS2 but I am trying to create an alternative to a hardware interface for my robot.
I have a diff drive vehicle. The main ROS program will run on an Ubuntu PC. The controller on the vehicle is an MyRio from National Instruments. From what I found online and what I tested. I am able to communicate from MyRIO to Labview and after that to ROS through DDS. Can't establish a connection from MyRIO directly to ROS (don't know why). But it works this way so all good.
MyRio does the encoder data acquisition and sends them via a topic to ROS (Encoder1,Encoder2) and also waits a PWM on (M1,M2 topics).
So my question is how can I evade having an hardware interface? How can I process the data provided by nav2 (/diff_cont/cmd_vel_unstamped) to get just a PWM on the 2 motors I have? Also where should I place the encoder data I receive?
I only tested the robot in a gazebo simulation but I have no idea how to advance to control the real robot.
Here is the robot repo if it is of any help: https://github.com/Serarguy/amr_platform
Any help is appreciated. Thanks a lot!

What do you mean by hardware interface? You mean a hardware component of the ros2_control stack?
From /diff_cont/cmd_vel_unstamped you need to calculate the wheel speeds by solving the kinematics of your robot. This is done by the diff_drive_controller already, but you need a hardware component then. Of course you could copy that in a custom node and leave the ros2_control stack, but then you can't just simply switch between simulation and hardware without changing your controller.
